Extensional context: "S believes in x"
I know that there is some research in philosophy on the difference between (A) "S believes that p" and (B) "S believes in x" (e.g. H. H. Price and Gendler Szabó). But I cannot find anything specific and (especially) formal on the logical structure of a sentence like "Anna believes in God". What I am most interested in: such a sentence seems to avoid any intensional context, because "believes in" expresses just a relation between two singular terms and not a relation between a singular term and a proposition (e.g. "Anna believes that God exists"). Therefore I am especially interested in the following questions:

Am I right that (B) does not trigger an intensional context?
Is there any research in compositional semantics on sentences with the logical form of (B)?
Is or can there be a general account for sentences like (B) or does the semantic analysis always depend on the singular term on the x-variable ("mapping problem")?

Thanks very much in advance.

I think this question is on-topic here, but as we tend not to get many questions on formal semantics, it's possible it may be more likely to receive good answers on the philosophy site
